# Python pickle._dumps works while pickle.dumps fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, pickle

I ran into an issue recently where I tried to do Pickle (Python 3.6) on an object of type:
`twilio.rest.chat.v2.service.channel.ChannelInstance` (The code for it can be found [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/tree/6.45.0). )

The relevant code was just this:

`picked_rv = pickle.dumps(value)`

it would result in: `TypeError: can’t pickle _thread.RLock objects` on our server
or
`AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'init_logging.<locals>.NotProductionHandler'`
on  my local system. Both `RLock` and `NotProductionHandler` are objects in the same environment as the `ChannelInstance` but not actually referenced by it at all, i.e. those are objects I instantiated in the same context while making a call to Twilio and getting the `ChannelInstance` back.

However, as soon as I try to use the pure Python Pickle instead of the cPickle (or _pickle in the module) `dumps` like this:

`picked_rv = pickle._dumps(value)`

it would work just fine. Can anyone explain the difference in behavior? I'm just baffled by both the error and difference in behavior. Why would cPickle try to pull in the other variables and objects in the context and then why would the pure Python implementation work?

This was not an issue with on [Twilio 6.18.0](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/tree/6.18.0), cPickle worked just fine, but I suspect the issue is Pickle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be using python-3.x. Why do you care about cPickle at all? It's an old Python-2.7 library.

Comment: @DYZ I must have misunderstood. I thought ```_pickle``` referenced in the ```pickle``` module is cPickle. I assumed that the following meant that it will try to load cPickle if possible.

    # Use the faster _pickle if possible
    try:
        from _pickle import (
            ...
        )
    except ImportError:
        Pickler, Unpickler = _Pickler, _Unpickler
        dump, dumps, load, loads = _dump, _dumps, _load, _loads

My code seems to work but I'm just perplexed by the difference between pickle.dumps and pickle._dumps.

Comment: I just tried this on Python 3.8 and the problem goes away. Unfortunately AWS currently only supports 3.6 on Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Also works on Python 3.7